# Create a Gson/Json object by a String

Tags: android, json, gson

I'm trying  to convert this string :

{"status":200,"message":"OK","response":{"result":1,"time":0.29773306846619,"values":[]}}

to a Json OBJ, to be able to read values better, I read somewhere that I can use Gson library, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use GSON. Android has JSON parsing builtin. Just pass your string to the constructor.

```
JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(myString);
```

[Here are the docs for JSONObject.](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html)

Comment: Thanks very much! :D